# xCode iOS Simulator lagging only in landscape

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

The title really says it all, I don't have any code that runs only in landscape, I really have no idea what could be causing this.  Everything runs perfectly in portrait. If anyone has any insight please let me know this is infuriating!

This issue was solved by cleaning the Project (Product>Clean in top toolbar)

Comment: Do you have landscape mode checked as orientations in General?

Comment: @Nik I'm completely new to the xcode IDE :P I have the orientation set to landscape under simulated metrics if that is what you mean.

Comment: In the project info there's a section called General. In it there's check boxes for landscape right, landscape left, portrait, and upside down. I don't have it in front of me so I may be off slightly

Comment: @Nik I found it and changed it but unfortunately no change there is still crazy lag :( Thanks anyways tho :)

Comment: Did you try rebooting Xcode and/or your computer. Also note that lag on the simulator doesn't mean the app actually lags. My game runs about 20 fps on sim but 60 fps on device. Try to recreate the problem on an actual device to see if it's a sim problem or code problem

Comment: @Nik Yes, rebooting has no effect :/

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried to recreate the lag on an actual device? You could try cleaning the project **Project > Clean** or **CMD-K** too

Comment: @Nik Runs fine on my phone, I just cleaned it and that fixed it! Thanks so much man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the project. **Shift-CMD-K** or **Project > Clean**